# NPM issue while running any npm commands

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-package

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                              operable program or batch file.

Comment: What command do you run?

Comment: Command I run: npm i

Answer (score 0):

Have u set the environment variables after the installation?
If not then try it first and let me know if u still have the error.

Comment: Environment variable already set after java installation I got this error I can run my project but couldn't install new packages